# Retrieving a count statement and send to client through signalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am currently a student trying to do mini projects for my school. I am totally a newbie for signalR. Please help me.

I am trying to get a count from the database and return it and send to clients that call that method/function. Then the Client will display in the web page.

**Startup**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using mini_project;

namespace mini_project
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
}
```

**Hub**

```
public class queryHub : Hub
{
    private static mpDBEntities db = new mpDBEntities();
    private int noG { get; set; }
    public void GetStatusG()
    {
        var x = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select COUNT(Room_Status.Status) from Room_Cur_Status, Room_Status where Room_Status_Id = Room_Status.Id AND Room_Status.Status = 'G'");
        //var x = db.Room_Cur_Status
        //    .Where(o => o.Room_Status.Status.Equals('G'))
        //    .Select(o => o.Room_Status.Status)
        //    .Count();
        Clients.All.getG(x);
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
<script>
    var chat;
    var noG;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chat = $.connection.queryHub;
        function Test() {
            noG = chat.client.getG;
        }
        $.connection.hub.start()
                    .done(function () {
                        console.log('connected');
                        Test();
                        console.log('Got It');
                        document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = noG
                    })
                .fail(function (ex) {
                    console.log('not connected' + ex);
                });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <p id="test1"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `getG` function inside your `document.ready` handler for your hub like so

```
chat.client.getG = function(x) {
  alert("I have received a value, here it is..." + x);
};
```

Also, you are probably not calling your `Hub` method anywhere, I usually like to provide `HubMethodName` attribute

```
[HubMethodName("GetStatusG")]
public void GetStatusG()
{
    var x = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select COUNT(Room_Status.Status) from Room_Cur_Status, Room_Status where Room_Status_Id = Room_Status.Id AND Room_Status.Status = 'G'");
    //var x = db.Room_Cur_Status
    //    .Where(o => o.Room_Status.Status.Equals('G'))
    //    .Select(o => o.Room_Status.Status)
    //    .Count();
    Clients.All.getG(x);
}
```

Also, I don't see anywhere in your client code where you are calling the `Hub` method. Try this

```
 <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />
```

then handle it

$("#update").click(function () {
 chat.server.GetStatusG();
});

So your client code becomes

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var chat;
    var noG;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chat = $.connection.queryHub;
        chat.client.getG = function (x) {;
          $("#test1").html("Hey I received a new value of x... " + x);
        }

$("#update").click(function () {
 chat.server.GetStatusG();
});
        $.connection.hub.start()
                    .done(function () {
                        console.log('connected');
                        Test();
                        console.log('Got It');
                    })
                .fail(function (ex) {
                    console.log('not connected' + ex);
                });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
         <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />
        <p id="test1"></p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the Damien Edward's `MoveShape` example that works on the new version of SignalR](http://www.fahadash.com/2015/05/signalr-damien-edwards-moveshape-sample.html)

Comment: "$(document).ready(function () {
   chat = $.connection.queryHub;
   $.connection.hub.start()
      .done(function () {
       console.log('connected');
       
      })
     .fail(function (ex) {
      console.log('not connected' + ex);
     });
   chat.client.getG = function (x) {
    console.log(x);
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = x
   };
  });" 

I added like this but it is still not working.

Comment: Is your hub is properly getting connected? are you getting any error message?

Comment: And where are you calling the  GetStatusG() on your server/hub?

Comment: Yes, I opened my console and check the log. The log got "Connected".

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna You don't seem to be calling your hub method anywhere, I updated your code and added the call.

Comment: It worked, but the number that came out is not the number I wanted.

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna That might be the error with your SQL Query, you may have to debug it to find out where the number is different. Post a separate question for this. You got the call working at least. Accept this as an answer if you agree.